# php artisan development server crashing

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-artisan

For my php laravel development I'm using the build-in webserver of php. I start it with the command "php artisan serve" on windows. For a few months it was working like a charm, but now it's all of a sudden crashing on pages that I didn't even change recently.

As soon as I try to load a page, I get this error:

[image]

It's in dutch, but it's just a general windows crash message.
In the log file I see:

```
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=null.ERROR: exception 'InvalidArgumentException' with message 'There are no commands defined in the "view" namespace.' in D:\home-automation\webInterface\vendor\symfony\console\Symfony\Component\Console\Application.php:501
Stack trace:
#0 D:\home-automation\webInterface\vendor\symfony\console\Symfony\Component\Console\Application.php(535): Symfony\Component\Console\Application->findNamespace('view')
#1 D:\home-automation\webInterface\vendor\symfony\console\Symfony\Component\Console\Application.php(192): Symfony\Component\Console\Application->find('view:clear')
#2 D:\home-automation\webInterface\vendor\symfony\console\Symfony\Component\Console\Application.php(126): Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRun(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
#3 D:\home-automation\webInterface\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel.php(94): Symfony\Component\Console\Application->run(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
#4 D:\home-automation\webInterface\artisan(36): Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel->handle(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
#5 {main}
```

I don't do anything with mail, so I don't think that "MAIL_ENCRYPTION" does have anything to do with it. The lines after it are probably the problem, but I have no idea what causes them or how I could resolve it.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok, solved it.

I had a error in a controller, that caused the crash if any method in the controller was accessed.

Instead of doing something like:

```
foreach ($sensorgroup->sensors as $sensor)
```

I had:

```
foreach ($sensor as $sensorgroup->sensors)
```

I don't know what I was thinking typing that, and neither did php. Bit stange that it crashed the whole thing instead of just throwing a error...